# How to preloading in gorm with a struct that have another struct from table?

Tags: go

It's me again.
I now can preloading in gorm...
But the issue is expand now.
I have 3 struct that need to get data
First is

```
type Deal struct{
DealId int
Attachments []Attachment
}
```

```
type Attachment struct{
DealId int
ProductId int
AttachmentId int
Product 
}
```

```
type Product struct{
ProductId int
}
```

So how to make both joins and preload in gorm with 3 table of mine? Any suggestion?
I need to take a deal relate with all the attachment... tried without product is ok. But when need the product... the problem is i can not joins it with attachment when preload
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all the information about nested preloading [here](https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html#Nested-Preloading).

For your case, it could look something like this:

```
var deals []Deal
err := db.Preload("Attachments").Preload("Attachments.Product").Find(&deals).Error
```

Comment: No problem :) . Please upvote it and check it as a working solution, if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's really helpful for newbie like me when first time trying golang and its framework

Comment: the problem with this solution is that it becomes slow when you are querying for thousands of deals